# Как сделать чтобы после нажатия звука включить звук, после рестарта уровня эта настойка сохранялась? В Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как сделать чтобы после нажатия звука включить звук, после рестарта уровня эта настойка сохранялась? В Unity

```
    public void MuteMusicToggle(){
    muteMusic = !muteMusic;

    if (musicSource != null) {
        musicSource.mute = muteMusic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде как-то через префаб можно сделать, но немного не понимаю как это реализовать!

Comment: неужто не сработал мой ответ?

Comment: Как можно нажать звук? Настойка? Отредактируйте свой вопрос. Ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Документация по PlayerPrefs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

можешь расширить базовый класс добавив екстеншном методы SetBool и GetBool:

```
 public static void SetBool(string key, bool state)
 {
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, state ? 1 : 0);
 }

 public static bool GetBool(string key)
 {
     return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key) == 1;
 }
```

и тогда пользоватся можно будет вот так:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetBool("SoundOn", true);

IsSoundOn = PlayerPrefs.GetBool("SoundOn");
```